# Why does GCC allow zero length array only as last member?

Tags: arrays, gcc

According to this,

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

It is said that the benefit is

> They are very useful as the last element of a structure that is really
>   a header for a variable-length object

What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zero-length array is a GCC extension (read as: not standard) which you should not use.

While recent versions of C allow for someting similar (flexible array member with empty brackets), C++ knows no such thing. As people often mix C and C++, this is a possible source of confusion.

Instead, an array of length `1` should be used, which is standards-compliant under both C and C++, and which *just works* with every compiler.

What is this useful for at all?

Sometimes you need to access "invalid" out-of-bounds data knowing that it is valid in reality. In the strictest sense, this is undefined behavior (since you are accessing out-of-bounds values which are indeterminate, and using indeterminate values is UB), but that is only for what the compiler knows, not for what it fact, so it nevertheless "works fine".

For example, you might receive framed data on the network consisting of a tag word, a length, and an amount of data corresponding to the length given. Or an operating system function might return a variable amount of results to you (a couple of Win32 API functions work that way, for example).
In either case, you have a unknown (unknown at compile time) number of elements at the end of this structure, so it is not possible to define a single legitimate structure to hold everything.
That is what flexible array members are for. And with this, it is explained why they must be the last member as well. It doesn't make sense for something that could have "any size" to be anywhere but at the end -- it's impossible for the compiler to lay out any members after it, not knowing its size.

(In case you wonder how the compiler can ever free the storage not knowing the objects's size... *it cannot!* There normally exists an explicit function for freeing such an object as part of the API, which takes care of this exact problem.)

Comment: Thanks for the concise explanation. It helps me to understand the logic behind the rather "strange" thing I see in the GCC standard.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to demonstrate with a small example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define BLOB_TYPE_FOO  0xBEEF


struct blob {
    /* Part of your object header... perhaps describing the type of blob. */
    int type;

    /* This is actually the length of the "data" field below */
    unsigned length;

    /* The data */
    unsigned char data[];
};


struct blob *
create_blob(int type, size_t size)
{
    /* Allocate enough space for the "header" and "size" bytes of data. */
    struct blob *x = calloc(1, sizeof(struct blob) + size);
    x->type = type;
    x->length = size;

    return x;
}


int
main(void)
{
    /* Note that sizeof(struct blob) doesn't include the data field. */
    printf("sizeof(struct blob): %zu\n", sizeof(struct blob));

    struct blob *x = create_blob(BLOB_TYPE_FOO, 1000);

    /*
        You can manipulate data here, but be careful not to exceed the
        allocated size.
    */

    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        x->data[i] = 'A' + (i % 26);
    }

    /*
        Since data was allocated with the rest of the header, everything is
        freed.
    */
    free(x);

    return 0;
}
```

The nice part about this setup is that `sizeof(struct blob)` represents the size of the "object header" (on my machine, that's 8 bytes), and that since you allocate the whole object together, a single `free()` is all that is needed to release the memory.

Like others have stated here, this is a non-standard extension and you should really consider using it with care.  Damon's answer is the better way to go, though the sizeof() operation is not quite the right size (it's a bit too large to represent the size of the actual header).  It's not too hard to workaround that problem though.

Comment: Thanks for the trouble of giving me the example. That helps me to get things in the less abstract way. (voted up)

Answer (score 0):

You cannnot have the array of 0 length because if you try to make a zero length array then it would mean that you are trying to create a pointer to *nothing* which is [not correct](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42121). The C standard says:

> - Flexible array members are written as contents[] without the 0.
> - Flexible array members have incomplete type, and so the sizeof operator may not be applied. As a quirk of the original implementation of zero-length arrays, sizeof evaluates to zero.
> - Flexible array members may only appear as the last member of a struct that is otherwise non-empty.
> - A structure containing a flexible array member, or a union containing such a structure (possibly recursively), may not be a member of a structure or an element of an array. (However, these uses are permitted by GCC as extensions.